# Has anyone seen this Penguin?

Tags: shirokuma-cafe

I came across [this page](http://www.stewpig.com/funny/the-weirdest-things-happen-on-anime-shows-19-pics/2013/05/29/) while stumbling through the internet and would like to know what show this is from.

[image: Penguin]

Comment: If you think *that's* weird, you'll faceplant at [this GIF from the same show](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2dc4cDtVb1qzqnxxo1_r2_500.gif).

Comment: @Eric aaaaaand added to Crunchyroll queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anime is [*Shirokuma Cafe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirokuma_Cafe), about animals and humans in a cafe run by a polar bear named Shirokuma (シロクマ); this penguin character is aptly named "Penguin".

[image: Penguin.]

Answer (score 4):

This is "Penguin" from *Shirokuma Cafe*, episode 9.

Penguin has an obvious crush on a female penguin named "Penko,"Shirokuma usually tries to helps him prepare for encounters with her... but Penguin always seems to chicken out at the very last moment.